# Sticky post in GitHub Page using plugin

Tags: github-pages

I want to have a post that will remain the first post on the page even when newer posts are created. I found this plugin https://github.com/ibrado/jekyll-stickyposts/

but i dont know what to write in `etc` in

```
{% assign sorted = paginator.posts | sort: "stickiness" %}
{% for post in sorted %}
...etc...
{% endfor %}
```

Also should I add to `_config.yml`

```
# Gems
plugins:
  - jekyll-stickyposts
```

The theme I'm using is Lanyon theme. My webpage can be found here https://github.com/psireal9/lanyon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have defined the plugin in your `_config.yml`, like you mentioned:

```
plugins:
    - jekyll-stickyposts
```

As the documentation for jekyll-stickynotes states:

If you're not using a paginator at all, use something like:

```html
{% assign sorted = site.posts | sort: "stickiness" %}
    {% for post in sorted %}
    ...etc...
{% endfor %}
```

If you're using the original jekyll-paginate:

```html
{% assign sorted = paginator.posts | sort: "stickiness" %}
    {% for post in sorted %}
    ...etc...
{% endfor %}
```

Your site appears to be using the original pagination, so the second option suits you. The `...etc...` is what you actually want to do with the sticky posts, the variable `post` can be used in the `for` loop and it will be equal to a stickied post from the `sorted` list which only contains sticky posts. From here, simply use HTML/CSS to style how you want the sticky to look at the top of the page. Keep in mind that this only **sorts** all your posts by stickied posts first, so you probably want to check to see if the post is a sticky post like so:

```html
{% assign sorted = paginator.posts | sort: "stickiness" %}
    {% for post in sorted %}
        {% if post.sticky %}
           <!-- Do something here with stickied post -->
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Put this code in your `/_layouts/page.html` to make it global across all pages, or `/_layouts/post.html` if you only want them to appear on top of posts.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I'm not familiar with HTML/CSS so if you can help a little bit more, I would gladly accept your answer as a solution and give you the bounty :) So i want to have ` lanyon/_posts/2020-07-06-introduction.md ` as the sticky post , i.e. the first post in the `Home` section and every other posts should appear in order of the date. How can I write this in HTML for the line `<!-- Do something here with stickied post -->` ?

Answer (score 0):

So yesterday, I found out solution to my own problem. It seems like the `plugin` (https://github.com/ibrado/jekyll-stickyposts/) doesn't work. So here are the steps:

1. Remove `jekyll-stickyposts` under `# Gems` in `_config.yml`
2. For post that you want it be to be sticky just add `sticky: true` to front matter. For ex:

```
---
layout: post
title: Introduction
sticky: true
---
```

3. Edit `class="posts"` in `index.html` as follows:

```
<div class="posts">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.sticky %}
  <div class="post">
    <h1 class="post-title">
      <a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h1>

    <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>

    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  
  {% for post in site.posts %}
  {% unless post.sticky %}
  <div class="post">
    <h1 class="post-title">
      <a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h1>

    <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span>

    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
  {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I havent tried out for posts not in the `Home` section but I think that would work.